# iOS : Repositioning UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-graphics, cgcontext

I've got code that allows me to draw on top of a UIImageView 
 - but I want to be able to limit the drawing area.

I've been able to limit the size, but now I'm unable to position it: if i change (0, 0) to anything else my image disappeared completely and the ability to draw stops working

drawImage - is a UIImageView

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(560, 660));
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 660)];

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    [drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 660)];
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    [self addSubview:drawImage];
}
```

any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but I'll take a swing:

```
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 660)];
```

This tells the image assigned to the `drawImage` to draw itself in the current context at `0,0`.  Since the context is a bitmap image context, its extent will be from `0,0` to `560,660`. It seems to me that this is probably what you want to do, otherwise you would have blank areas in your bitmap. If you were to change that `0,0` to `10,0`, I would expect there to be a 10pt wide blank area in the resulting bitmap (which seems like a waste).

Then later you do this:

```
[drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 660)];
```

This is setting the UIImageView's coordinates in its superview's coordinate system.  If you change *that* `0,0` to, say, `5,5` I would expect your UIImageView to appear 5pt down and 5pt to the right in its superview.

You say you want to "limit the drawing area." I assume you mean the part where you're drawing over the image. The easiest way to do that would be to set a clip rect on the bitmap context before you draw.  For instance, if you wanted to prevent drawing in a 10pt band around the edge of the image, you could do that like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(560, 660));
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 660)];

CGContextClipToRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(10,10,540,640));
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
// ... and so on
```

Not 100% sure if that's what you're looking for, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: tanks a lot for the explanation :

Answer (score 1):

try by restricting the `currentPoint`

```
if (currentPoint.x <= 20 || currentPoint.x >= 280 || 
    currentPoint.y <= 20 || currentPoint.y >= 400)
{
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    return;
}
```